# Is there a way to resume from a failed job in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

I am using 4 Jenkin jobs for Continuous Build and Deployment.The jobs are created for label creation, build using the label, deploy to server1 and deploy to server2 and so on..

The Create_label build will run the MYSQL query in database and get the label. Create_label job on success will invoke the Build-job with the label and upon successful completion of Build-Job, it will invoke Deploy-server1 job and so on..

If the build fails in Build-Job and after that If I start the 1st Create-Label job then it runs the job and creates the NEW label. I mean running the create-label every time will get you incremental label. I can only get the label from 1st job and then pass to 2nd job. Can anyone suggest how to resume from the failed job with out running the first job and start with second job using the old label created(from the last build in 1st job). any work around to accomplish this type of situation in jenkins.

1.Create-Label
2.Build-Job
3.Deploy-server1
4.Deploy-server2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems, you have 2 issue at the moment:

Issue 1 --> If any job fails, the next time it should skip the successful jobs and restart only from the failed job.

Probable Solution --> You could use Build Pipeline plugin, https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Pipeline+Plugin , and if the job fails at say second job, then all you have to do is restart the second job from the pipeline and it would continue from there.

Issue 2 --> For job 2, you not only want to restart it but have to take the input, Label Number, from the previous successful job 1, without restarting job 1

Unfortunately, I don't have a clean automated solution for this. The only thing I can think of requires manual intervention, i.e. since this job is parameterized, change the default value of the parameter to the Label Number from the last successful job 1 before restarting it from plugin(The above plugin doesn't ask for parameters while running the job)

or let Job1 login the label number in some centralized location and let job B take the parameter from there instead of taking it from jobA.

Thanks,
Manish Joshi

Answer (score 1):

I am using [MultiJob plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/jenkins-multijob-plugin) and you can always just click "**Resume build**" in the parent job to continue from a failed job.

And in this case the parameters for its execution will be all the same as on those previous run which failed.

Comment: unfortunately this only solves the 1st problem from @ManishJoshi's answer, but not the 2nd